# Почему код со сменой стилей не рабоатает?

Tags: javascript, html, css

При клике на иконку, должна вызываться функция которая смотрит, если у элемента в свойствах display:none, то сделать его display:block, и наоборот.

В консоли ошибок нет

```js
function AdaptiveMenu() {
 var Adaptive = document.getElementById('menu');
 var AdaptiveStyle = getComputedStyle(Adaptive);
 if (AdaptiveStyle.display == 'none') {
  AdaptiveStyle.display == 'block';
 };
}
```

```css
.ico {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.rect {
  width: 30px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.menu {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ico" onclick='AdaptiveMenu'>
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
</div>

<nav class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>lit-item</li>
    <li>lit-item</li>
    <li>lit-item</li>
    <li>lit-item</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и с иконкой, и с элементом, и со стилями элемента

Comment: `и наоборот.` - а где ваш "наоборот"?

Comment: Я пока еще наоборот не делал.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Laa3yqby/5/ - Вот в чем проблема.

Comment: `onclick='AdaptiveMenu()'` ← надо так

Comment: У вас как минимум три ошибки: 1) вы не вызываете функцию, нужно дописать скобки `onclick='AdaptiveMenu()'`; 2) Вы вместо присваивания делаете сравнение, нужно так: `AdaptiveStyle.display = 'block';`; 3) Эта строчка всё равно не заработает, потому что это объект стилей только для чтения, стили нужно менять у самого элемента: `Adaptive.style.display = 'block';`

Comment: Я случайно на JS фидле не поставил, код все равно не работает :)

Comment: Это я писал ответ на прошлый, про то что я функцию неправильно вызвал, а если три исправить то и в правду работает, огромное спасибо :)

Comment: ну проблема тогда вот  тут `AdaptiveStyle.display == 'block';` и надо писать  `Adaptive.style.display = 'block';`

Comment: @uzi_no_uzi `Я случайно на JS фидле не поставил,` - в следующий раз надо **точно** писать тот код, который имеется. Потому что могут закрыть как опечатку...... хотя и сейчас наверное так закроют

Answer (score 1):

Описание ошибок в комментариях в коде

```js
var Adaptive = document.getElementById('menu');

function AdaptiveMenu() {
  // не var AdaptiveStyle = getComputedStyle(Adaptive) , а 
  var AdaptiveStyle = getComputedStyle(Adaptive).getPropertyValue('display');

  if (AdaptiveStyle == 'none') {
    // ты проверяешь в условии  AdaptiveStyle.display == 'block';
    //а потом по мимо тог, что присваеваешь стили не той переменной
    // ты не присваеваешь а сравниваешь
    //AdaptiveStyle.display == 'block';
    Adaptive.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    Adaptive.style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

```css
.ico {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.rect {
  width: 30px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

#menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- не AdaptiveMenu, а AdaptiveMenu()  -->
<div class="ico" onclick="AdaptiveMenu()">
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
  <div class="rect"></div>
</div>

<nav class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>lit-item</li>
    <li>lit-item</li>
    <li>lit-item</li>
    <li>lit-item</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```